# Data is not getting inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

When i am try to save my form data to `sql` database on button click data is not save to table. here is my `web.config` file and code behind file.

web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" connectionString="Data Source=admin-pc\SQLEXPRESS;database=abc;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Here is my code behind file
aspx.cs:

```
public partial class registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=admin-pc\SQLEXPRESS ; Database=abc; Integrated Security=true");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFistname.Text = "";
        txtlastname.Text = "";
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";

        txtcontac.Text = "";
        txtPassword.Text = "";
        txtconPassword.Text = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into reg(FName,LName,Gender,email,contact,password,conpasswd) values('" + txtFistname.Text + "','" + txtlastname.Text + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtcontac.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "','" + txtconPassword.Text + "')", con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Data inserted successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind file aspx.cs file try this code:

```
public partial class registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString()
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFistname.Text = "";
        txtlastname.Text = "";
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";

        txtcontac.Text = "";
        txtPassword.Text = "";
        txtconPassword.Text = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into reg(FName,LName,Gender,email,contact,password,conpasswd) values('" + txtFistname.Text + "','" + txtlastname.Text + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtcontac.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "','" + txtconPassword.Text + "')", con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("Data inserted successfully");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Somethings goes wrong" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```